# Implement a strategy for html5 angular views that once I change the view and deploy it, the browser should not use the cached version

Tags: angularjs, html, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, browser-cache

Implement a strategy for html5 angularjs views that once I change the view and deploy it, the browser should not use the cached version.

I tried using the URL?v=1.0.1 idea but then it forces the app to load the html page every time from the server, the way I would prefer is that the browser caches the page on load and keeps using the cached version until a newer version is deployed, so some kind of cache breaker strategy for HTML pages. And I have tried many html cache breakers most of them do the same thing force load the HTML page each time, which is not ideal, my middle tier is ASP .NET WEB API and front end is AngularJS. Not sure if there is a server side setting I can do to achieve the result I intend to.

Comment: Change the name of the file when you update it. So, "index.html" becomes "index_v1.0.html", "index_v1.1.html", etc.. There are build tools which can do that automatically for you as well, but that depends on what you're using to build your web app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I accomplished this using HTML5 Manifest file :), and I use my build process to update the manifest file so that the browser is forced to get a fresh copy of the changed html files.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on how you did?

Comment: I followed the tutorial here https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to achieve it. I use global variables. For example,

### [Sample code 1](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet/blob/master/src/Presentation/AngularAspNet.Web/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml)

```
window.App = {
   version: '1.1.0.1 beta',
   rootPath: '/'
}
```

*Note: I use ASP.Net MVC's cshtml as strongly-typed Angular view; you can just replace a server-side code with regular text.*

### [Sample Code 2](https://github.com/WinLwinOoNet/AngularAspNet/blob/master/src/Presentation/AngularAspNet.Web/App/Users/Components/UserList.js)

```
angular
   .module("users")
   .component("userList", {
   templateUrl: window.App.rootPath + "Users/Components/UserList.cshtml?v=" 
       + window.App.version,
      controller: UserListController
});
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but what i have noticed is that (and i have mentioned that in my question as well) if u put v=1.0*** something at the end of the url, it forces a get on the html from server each time, in the chrome dev tools under network tab you can see what is coming from server and what is coming from cache, and in this case i never see it coming from cache.